# Function that return an error if it fails

Tags: c, error-handling

I am wondering which of the following solutions would be the best and why.

#### Solution 1

```
bool foo(void)
{
   if (is_true())
      return true; // Error
   else
      return false; // No error
}
```

#### Solution 2

```
bool foo(void)
{
   if (is_true())
      return false; // Error
   else
      return true; // No error
}
```

#### Solution 3

```
int foo(void)
{
   if (is_true())
      return -1; // Error
   else
      return 0;  // No error
}
```

#### Solution 4

```
size_t foo(void)
{
   if (is_true())
      return SIZE_MAX; // Error
   else
      return 0;  // No error
}
```

One will say a function named `is_raining()` should return `false` when it's not raining however, with `bash` a program that return `0` means success. A negative value is often considered as an error but then, how do I know how I should treat my return code?

```
if(foo())
   printf("Error\n");

if(!foo())
   printf("Error\n");

if(foo() < 0)
   printf("Error\n");
```

Comment: It's matter of context. Like you say, a function like `is_raining` should return true if it's raining, and false otherwise, but for like a function like `calculate_some_number` returning true or false makes no sense. However, how do you return an error from a function that returns a boolean value? In C the traditional way is to return an `int` and use `0` for "false", `1` for "true" and `-1` for "error". In the end, it's up to you, the main thing is that you *document* it, and that you are consistent.

Comment: and a function named `is_sunny_day` shouldn't return true if it's raining - The `foo()` you have chosen isn't really telling us what it should return; a 'foo', maybe? A function named `is_<condition>` should return a non-zero value if `<condition>` is true - because then you can write `if`- statements like `if (is_raining()){...}`.

Comment: Also, all of your examples only return *two* cases - Something is true, or an error occured. In real life, there is nearly always three of them - `is_raining()` could need to return `true`, `false` and "don't know, shutters closed"

Comment: None of your options can be considered 'best' or indeed 'worst' as none of the options is applicable to all functions. The primary consideration is that the error value must be distinguishable from any valid return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method you could use is to pass the function a pointer to an error structure such as:

```
struct{
    int errorcode;
    char* errormessage;
} typedef Error_Structure;

void foo(Error_Structure* error){
      if(is_True()){
          error->errorcode = 1;
          error->errormessage = "it was true!";
          return;
      }
}

int main(void){
    Error_Structure error;
    foo(&error);
    if(error->errorcode != 0){
         printf(error->errormessage);
    }
}
```

This way with more complex applications with regards to the foo function, the error codes can be more explanatory to the developer and end user for troubleshooting errors.

Comment: I'm suprised that `struct{
    int errorcode;
    char* errormessage;
} typedef Error_Structure;` compiled. The usual way would be `typedef struct {
    int errorcode;
    char* errormessage;
} Error_Structure;`. BTW, `error` is uninitialized and you dereference it from the function = UB.

Comment: Woops, don't work with C too much, I'm more familiar with seeing the typedef at the end. But yeah the dereferencing was silly. So it should be in the main function:     Error_Structure error;foo(&error);

Comment: I suggest [editing your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36530029/edit) to correct the mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer integer as return code. It is what most functions do in C.
In this way the function is extensible, you can add more error codes.

The code which uses this function can choose between:

- treat all error codes the same e.g print only "error"  (return value < 0), or
- finer error handling, test all error codes.

Comment: Extending this answer, a trick I've seen in NI software is to install a file which provides descriptions based on integer error codes. You can then update this file without recompiling your code and update error descriptions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is your choice, to my mind. If you think that some function should return `false` on error, make it do so.

For example:

```
bool valid() {
    if (1 == 1) return true;
    return false;
}

if (not valid()) { // clear enough, eh?
    /* do something */
}
```

If your function *is supposed to return a negative value on error*, make it do so.

```
int sqrt(int x) {
    if (x < 0) return -1;
    // do something and return a valid value 
}
```

So you know that `sqrt` can't be negative and then understand that if you got `-1`, then it's an error.

You can also return `true` *if you want to*:

```
bool ErrorOccurred() {
    if (errno == 5) return true;
    return false;
}

if (ErrorOccurred()) { // very easy to understand
    puts("There was an error!");
} else {
    puts("Everything is OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it's the question of what you prefer. But in my opinion true-false is best way to implicate an error in C (unless you want to work in C++, which has much better error handling in form of exceptions).

You can use the solution 2 and then:

```
if(!foo())
   printf("Error\n");
```

might be the easiest to understand. There is no difference in speed of program, whatever of these you use, so basically you are just thinking about the simplest and well-organised code. 
Also, if you want to use bool, that means you need to include:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```